# I want Android progress dialog to stay on screen until function on new activity is complete but doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

In my Android app, one form has a button which upon click opens up another; the new form performs activities which can take a while. I want the first form to remain open and for the progress dialog to keep spinning while these activities finish.

I've attempted this below, but it just won't work. The progress dialog just finishes and opens up the next window (before described activities on new form have finished)

In the below code SecondForm -

The subroutine "**Calculations**", is what takes a while to complete

Code:

**MainActivity:**

```
final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
            MainActivity.this);
    ringProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    ringProgressDialog.show();
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                SecondForm.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}).start();
```

**SecondForm:**

```
 public class CategoryTabs extends Fragment {

        static Context mContext;
        View rootView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                gotstatdata = false;
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_abc, container, false);

            mContext = rootView.getContext();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                gotstatdata = false;
                                Calculations(128);
                                gotstatdata = true;
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: where is the code that take a while to perform ?

Comment: Whether start the second activity and show progress dialog till the calculations method is finished, or you can move the calculation method calling to the first activity such that the second activity is not shown till the calculations method is done

Comment: Have you considered using an `AsyncTask`? I think it would be very fitting for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dismissing your dialog as soon as it runs with `ringProgressDialog.dismiss();`. 
That line should be removed and you should do something like send out a broadcast when you are finished to close the progress dialog.

It looks like you might also just want a background thread rather than a second `Activity` because no user interaction is required.

Looking at [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would be the easiest way for you to start with background threads and it's 'onPostExecute` method will allow you to dismiss your dialog.

**Edit**

The basic structure you want is to add the following

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //TODO: show your dialog from here
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //TODO: call Calculations(128); from here
            //Calculations(128); should live within this async task instead of a new activity
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //TODO: call dismiss on your dialog from here
        }
    }.execute();
```

instead of the `new Thread(new Runnable() {` block you currently have

Comment: I've never used this before, could you please show a code example?

Comment: I can see how the above may make sense for activities taking place on the same form. But in my above code, the activities take place on another form than the one creating the progressdialog

Comment: if you start another 'form' which seems to be what you are calling Activities then no UI from the previous activity can show, including the dialog. What you want is to do something in the background, which is what the asynctask is allowing you to do